# How to assign value to global variable in Javascript with a button click?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, javascript-controller

Is there any way to assign value to global variable in salesforce helper javascript?

**Helper**

```
({
    resetTime: 30000,
    refreshNotif: function(component, helper) {

            window.setInterval(
                $A.getCallback(function() {
                    console.log('test 1');
                }),
                helper.resetTime

            );
        },
 updateRead: function(component, helper) {
        helper.resetTime = 50000;

}
})
```

my question is, when page loads the refreshNotif function is getting called and the reset time value should be 30000. but when updateRead function is called how can i assign the value 50000 to resetTime global variable so that  helper.resetTime in the refreshNotif function should also get updated to 50000.

is my approach above is correct?

Right now the value is set to 30000 even when the second function getting called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Aura attribute to store the `resetTime` value, you can easily access that from the helper.

```
<aura:attribute name="resetTime" type="Integer" default="30000"/>
```

set that from helper

```
updateRead: function(component, helper) {
    component.set("v.resetTime", 50000);
}
```

get it like this,

```
let time = component.get("v.resetTime");
```

Comment: it worked. thanks

Comment: @Arzad Most welcome!

Comment: is there a way to declare global variable without initializing a value in JS controller in salesforce? 
Ex:
 resetTime: ,
    refreshNotif: function(component, helper) {
// 
}

assigning values to global variable dynamically?

Comment: @Arzad you can set it to undefined, but I doubt if you can change that value later. In my personal opinion it is always better to use `aura:attribute`.